# C function with same name returning different data values

Tags: c, function, parameters, return-value, return-type

I want to create 2 functions with the same name, same parameters but returning different data types. Is is possible in C? Thank you.

UPDATE: I've create a string reverse function. I want to return a new string or return void.

something like:

```
void reverse(char string[]);
char * reverse(char string[]);
```

Thank you everybody.

Comment: Perhaps you could offer a little more context as to why you want these two functions, someone could probably offer a solution to your problem if we knew what it really was.

Comment: Is it too hard to ignore return value of function?

Comment: So, how are you going to tell the compiler which function you want to call in each case?

Answer (score 6):

No, it isn't - it's not possible in C++ either. If it were, how would you call them? C simply doesn't have function overloading, and in C++ the return type is not considered when resolving overloads. Just give the functions different names. For example:

```
void Reverse( char * s );
char * MakeReversedCopy( const char * s );
```

Comment: Naively, one might guess that it would select by looking at what type the result is cast to or used to initialize, just as the `&` operator does when taking an address of an overloaded function. Probably best that it doesn't, though, since the interaction between overloads on parameter types and overloads on return types would almost certainly mean easy-to-make errors where you think you're calling a "returns an int" version, but you're actually calling a "returns a long" version and converting the result to int.